# access shared data source by report designer, created in SSRS web portal

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I recently started learning SSRS; I created a data source over SSRS web-portal; I am wandering whether such a data source can be accessed from /by Report Designer to create report and data sets.

Would anyone please help me understand the scope of such data source created in SSRS web-portal.

Thank you for giving your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you will create your shared data sources in Visual Studio/Report Designer and then publish them to the server. The end results is that you will have a data source available on the server (as it sounds like you have now).

By default data sources are not overwritten when you deploy reports, the idea is that you can have a data source on your development machine and as long as it has the exact same name on the server, when you deploy your report, it will look for the data source of the same name.

As it sounds like you created the data source directly from the web portal, you will have to recreate it on your development machine with the same name, when you deploy the report it will use the version on the server.

This also means that you can have a data source on your development machine, called `dsSales` for example and it might point to `myTestServer\myDatabase` and on the production server you could have a data source with the same name, pointing to `myProductionServer\myDatabase` (assuming the same tables etc exist on both) then you can test with data from the test server and when you deploy it will connect using the data source that connects to the production server.

I hope that clears it up a little.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... Alan